# Sub Query Alias in Group By Not Working Invalid Columns ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using a sub query in a sql query. but unfortunately when i try to use it in group by column i am getting INVALID COLUMN error. what is solution?

[image]

Comment: You tagged this as `oracle`, but use syntax like `[dbo].[tbl_VoucherType]`. This is not Oracle syntax. Are you sure you are using Oracle? In any case: at least in Oracle, you can't `GROUP BY` a column that is only created in the `SELECT` clause. `SELECT` is evaluated only **after** `GROUP BY`, not before it. So - if the query is otherwise correct (no way of knowing by just looking at a query), the solution is to create this latest version of `ll` in a subquery and group by it in an outer query. By the way, naming many things by the same alias is asking for trouble, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Actually we **can** tell that the query is otherwise incorrect, **if** in fact you are using Oracle. The keyword `AS` can be used in Oracle before **column** aliases (it is optional, you may use it or omit it), but it is **prohibited** before **table** aliases.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to read `tbl_AccountLedger` data again in `select` clause, because you already have it by `joins`(by same connection/condition), just replace your `(select......) ll` part with `l.ledgerName` like this

```
select l.ledgerName, sum(m.debit), sum (m.credit),
  from tbl_LedgerPosting  as m 
   left join [dbo].[tbl_VoucherType] as v on m.voucherTypeId=v.voucherTypeId
   left join [dbo].[tbl_AccountLedger] as l on m.ledgerId=l.ledgerId
group by v.coucherTypeName, m voucherNo, l.ledgerName
order by v.coucherTypeName, m voucherNo
```